# Inheritance - Invoke child methods instead of parent

Tags: c#, oop, inheritance, abstract-class, abstract

It is going to be hard to explain why Im doing the things im about to show you, but they have a reason so stay with me here. (suggestions are welcome).

I have a Functor which invokes a method on its input.

**!Please note!** the functor is actually an extension method so there must be a typing inference.

Also, I have an abstract class with 2 childs and an interface which demands a method signature.

The example code looks like this:

```
public sealed class AbstractionTester
{
    internal static void Run()
    {
        // The functor here accepts A type but in my original code its just a generic type. 
        // I wanted to keep it simple for this example only 
        Func<A, bool> func = a =>
        {
            a.CallMe(); //Displays "Error"
            return true;
        };

        B obj = new B();
        func(obj);
    }
}

internal interface ICallMe<T> 
    where T : MyEntity
{
    T CallMe();
}

//Just a class which holds data I would like to store about every object I have, for example: CreateDate
internal abstract class MyEntity
{ }

internal abstract class A : MyEntity, ICallMe<A>
{
    //some other fields i would like to store..

    // This method here must never be invoked
    public A CallMe()
    {
        //throw new Exception();
        Console.WriteLine("Error");
        return this;
    }
}

internal class B : A, ICallMe<B>
{
    public new B CallMe()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("B");
        return this;
    }
}

internal class C : A, ICallMe<C>
{
    public new C CallMe()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("C");
        return this;
    }
}
```

Everytime I call Run() the result is the **Error** is yeilded to the screen.
What can I do to enforce that this functor I have won't execute the method in the parent class.

Functor will never receive an instance of A anyway, because A is abstract (I mean pure A, not child of A)

Additional info:

- I must explicity write the return types of `CallMe` in class `B` and `C`. I CANNOT change them to type `A`.
- I need to keep the type of A (or something similar) in the functor because I need to infer the type for some code continuation.

Comment: Why don't you `override` in B class method of A, but rather use `new` ?

Comment: @Tigran because the method CallMe is defined in the interface

Comment: How would you implement the same generic interface twice? Which only differs in return type?

Comment: @JeroenvanLangen where did i say i implenet a generic interace twice? 
if you refer for the functor parameter type, its infering the type because the functor is actually an extension method in my code.
if you refer to the fact that i write ICallMe<T>, this example is minimized to the issue, in the original code i use it on almost every class i have.

Comment: It's here: `internal abstract class A : MyEntity, ICallMe<A>`   and here `internal class B : A, ICallMe<B>`  So: `ICallMe<A>` and `ICallMe<B>` and thats the problem. They enforce the implementation of 2 methods with different return types. You can't define the same methodname which only differs in return type. (overloading problem)  If you change the return type from `T CallMe();` to `void CallMe(out T t)` it will work.

Comment: Can you use a variation on the curiously recurring template pattern where A has a generic type parameter of the child class, or would that fall down in trying to make your function objects?

Comment: @Craig i noticed you posted and deleted this suggestion. I think i might do it but i have no idea what are the performance implications of this. i afried it might go into recursive type infering in case of an error.

Comment: @Craig Here's an example if you change it from a return parameter to an out parameter: https://dotnetfiddle.net/FaXMeq

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is really weird implementation. Why dont you use **Visitor pattern**?

Then you can do:

```
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Element a = new A();
        Element b = new B();
        Element c = new C();
        ICallMe callMe = new CallMe();
        a.accept(callMe);
        b.accept(callMe);
        c.accept(callMe);
    }
```

Implementation below:

```
public interface ICallMe
{
    void Visit(A a);
    void Visit(B b);
    void Visit(C c);
}

public class CallMe : ICallMe
{
    public void Visit(A c)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("A");
    }

    public void Visit(B b)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("B");
    }

    public void Visit(C a)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("C");
    }
}

interface Element
{
    void accept(ICallMe visitor);
}

public class A : Element
{
    public void accept(ICallMe visitor)
    {
        visitor.Visit(this);
    }
}
public class B : Element
{
    public void accept(ICallMe visitor)
    {
        visitor.Visit(this);
    }
}
public class C : Element
{
    public void accept(ICallMe visitor)
    {
        visitor.Visit(this);
    }
}
```

Comment: I actually went for dynamic dispatching at the end but i might change it to visitor pattern (which i also thought about when i wrote dynamic dispatch) and its seem to be the solution.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a solution that works without defining `public A CallMe()` as `virtual`. This has the benefit that child classes can define their `CallMe()` as `new` so they can return `B` or `C`. But it requires that you can make the classes `public` instead of `internal` (or you will get [an error](http://Help%20needed%20with%20TypeAccessException:%20Attempt%20by%20method%20%E2%80%A6%20to%20access%20type%20%E2%80%A6%20failed)).

Use dynamic dispatch to call the actual runtime type instead of the type declared in the interface:

```
Func<A, bool> func = a => {
     var runtimeType = (dynamic)a;
     runtimeType.CallMe(); 
     return true;
 };
```

[.net Fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/20qG4W)

Comment: i would rather not use casting unless it absolutely required

Comment: Sorry, the only other way that comes to my mind would be using `virtual`, which does not meet your requirements :(

Answer (score 0):

There is a specific language feature for this; interface reimplementation.

Reimplement explicitly the interface and make the generic functor take an `ICallable<T>`:

```
internal class B : A, ICallMe<B>
{
    B ICallable<B>.CallMe()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("B");
        return this;
    }
} 

internal class C : A, ICallMe<C>
{
    B ICallable<C>.CallMe()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("B");
        return this;
    }
}
```

And your functor should be:

```
Func<T, bool> func = a => ...
```

And `T` should be constrained (at method or class level) to `ICallable<T>`.

*UPDATE*: If the functor is really an extension code, I'm not sure what the issue is:

```
 public static bool MyEnxtensionMethod<T>(T argument)
     where T: ICallable<T>
 {
      argument.CallMe();
      return true;
 }
```

Why do you need to keep `A` anywhere?

Comment: I dont want to make a constraint between functor's parameter and ICallable<T>. i need to identify the type in there.
if you read my post carefully, i mentioned that the functor is in-fact an extension method so I need to keep the type A in there.

Comment: @OriRefael Then how are you considering making it generic (as you point out in your question) and call `CallMe()` if you dont somehow constraint the generic type so the compiler knows the call is safe?

Comment: @OriRefael What is the signature of your extension method? Its hard to give answers if you dont post relevant code.

Answer (score 0):

The best way to ensure that A's `CallMe` method is never invoked is for it to *not exist.*

```
internal abstract class MyEntity
{ }

internal abstract class A : MyEntity
{ }
```

Now it can never be invoked as you required.

Now make the interface covariant:

```
internal interface ICallMe<out T> 
    where T : MyEntity
{
    T CallMe();
}
```

Then change `Func<A, bool>` to `Func<ICallMe<A>, bool>`

```
public sealed class AbstractionTester
{
    internal static void Run()
    {
        // The functor here accepts A type but in my original code its just a generic type. 
        // I wanted to keep it simple for this example only 
        Func<ICallMe<A>, bool> func = a =>
        {
            a.CallMe(); //Displays "B"
            return true;
        };

        B obj = new B();
        func(obj);
    }
}
```